# How set a large Numpy in temporary variable to write a video?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, video-streaming, video-processing

Hi could you give me some help here? My intent in this code is a simple threshold in a serie of images that compose a video. The main problem is I can't store 237 frame in a single variable, in these case, := outputdata

The video in question I wanna thresh has a shape of (284,640,352,3). As you see at 22 line i will kill the rgb channel because further only grayscale is needed to threshold method. So this gives me an np.array bigger than 63Gb

you may find weird set manual outputdata index in video.nextFrame() loop;  but only in this way i make the code run without error. But when I see value of outputdata variable on debugger they show me all nested np.arrays filled with -1

```
import skvideo.io
import skvideo.datasets
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import time

def threshOneFrame(frame):
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (7, 7), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred,20,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    thresh = thresh[1].astype(np.uint8)
    return thresh

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", required=True,
    help="path to input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

vidSh = skvideo.io.vread(args["video"])
vidSh = vidSh.shape[:3]

video = skvideo.io.FFmpegReader(args["video"])
outputdata = np.zeros(vidSh, dtype=np.int8)

for id ,frame in enumerate(video.nextFrame()):
    frame = threshOneFrame(frame)
    outputdata[id] = frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break



lapstime = time.time()
skvideo.io.vwrite("outputvideo"+time.ctime(lapstime)+".mp4", outputdata)
video.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, the output video is unreasonably large to hold all of its frames at once uncompressed in memory.

The solution to this is to write output frames to disk as you create them. One way to do that: create an [skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/modules/generated/skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter.html#skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter) instance, then in for loop, call `writer.writeFrame(frame)` to write out the frame.

Or another possibility: use e.g. the PIL library to write each frame as an image file: `Image.fromarray(frame).save(f'frame-{id:06}.png')`. Then, outside of Python, run [FFmpeg to convert the images to a video](https://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/).

Comment: running like a rabit, tks for it. This issue make me currious about how memory stuff work under the hood. Questions like: how I know size memory of a variable? Do you've some material or doc to point me?

Comment: For a numpy array `x` of a numeric dtype, `x.nbytes` is the size of all its element data in bytes. Or here is an easy trick: use Windows Resource Monitor or `top` or similar to watch memory use of your program as a whole.